# FilterTweepy streaming on polarity

Tags: streaming, tweepy

Using streaming API I am trying to get Tweets with positive polarity on a particular topic. My filter statement is something like this

```
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
.......
    twitterStream = Stream(auth, listener())

    try:
        twitterStream.filter(track=["Trump :)"],languages=['en'])
    except:
        print("Streaming error")
```

Objective is to get Positive tweets on a subject. However I am not getting any response. I am unable to resolve the problem.

Comment: Ups! there was an error before the filter portion. Sorry filter is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Working fine. Error was some where else. Filter code given above is correct.